# How to convert List of list to Hashset in Java using Lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have a class that contains the user data.

```
public class UserData {
    @JsonProperty("uid")
    private String userId;

    @JsonProperty("cities")
    private List<Integer> cities;

}
```

From the `List<UserData>`, I want to extract all the unique cities. Changes, I am doing for this,

```
Set<Integer> citiesList = new HashSet<>();

for (UserData userData : userDataList)
       citiesList.addAll(userData.getCities());
```

What could be the `lambda` expressions of these changes?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how a lambda expression would fit in there. Unless you mean you want to do this using streams?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It feels like you should use [`.flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) with [`List.stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--) operation, not a specific lambda expression:

```
Set<Integer> citiesList = userDataList.stream()
  .map(UserData::getCities)
  .flatMap(List::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that the returned `Set` is a `HashSet`, you must use `Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)`, like this:

```
userDataList.stream().map(d -> d.getCities())
      .flatMap(d -> d.stream())
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```